# Malformed Response from Google Dialog Fulfillment with C# Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm developing a program that receives a Google Action Request (with fulfillment) in the form of a https-triggered Azure Function program (this is the part I'm coding). 
Right now, I'm able to receive the request. However, when I try to return a response, the Google simulator says I have this as the response:

```
{
"responseMetadata": {
"status": {
  "code": 10,
  "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
      "value": "{\"id\":\"dd9eda55-a5b3-4b8f-be38-2eb50ff840d4\",\"timestamp\":\
                "2019-03-05T13:37:36.852Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\
                "alternateResult\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\
                "partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: Failed 
                 to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got: \\\
                "笀∀昀甀氀昀椀氀氀洀攀渀琀吀攀砀琀∀㨀∀吀栀爀漀眀 戀愀渀愀渀愀 漀甀琀 䄀渀礀眀栀攀爀攀∀Ⰰ∀昀甀氀昀椀氀氀洀攀渀琀䴀攀猀猀愀最攀猀∀㨀嬀崀Ⰰ∀猀漀甀爀挀攀∀㨀∀∀Ⰰ∀瀀愀礀氀漀愀搀∀㨀渀甀氀氀Ⰰ∀漀甀琀瀀甀琀䌀漀渀琀攀砀琀猀∀㨀嬀崀Ⰰ∀昀漀氀氀漀眀甀瀀䔀瘀攀渀琀䤀渀瀀甀琀∀㨀渀甀氀氀紀\\\".\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHGecG8tTLQ_DS7c3EL0l80w7YLzwAC8NFid9fVPnvYpD0s9QPo_Vnib3riGZ-8qDVI5vPnaKON1hVnC\"}"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

This is how I'm receiving the request:

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, /*"get",*/ "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request."); 

        string json = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true));
    googleRequest = jsonParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(json);
```

The response function is this at the moment:

```
public OkObjectResult response(String output)
{
    WebhookResponse googleResponse = new WebhookResponse();
    googleResponse.FulfillmentText = output;

    return new OkObjectResult(googleResponse);//This is returned from the main function
}
```

Also, I'm using ngrok to test with the google simulator

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd the same issue. Instead of using

```
public OkObjectResult response(String output)
{
    WebhookResponse googleResponse = new WebhookResponse();
    googleResponse.FulfillmentText = output;

    return new OkObjectResult(googleResponse);//This is returned from the main function
}
```

Try something like this:

```
    var returnString = googleResponse.ToString();
    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = returnString,
        ContentType = "application/json",
        StatusCode = 200
    };
```

Please look at this [link](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/50599456/dialogflow+fails+to+parse+the+json+response+from+my+webhook+seems+to+change+character+encoding) why use ContentResult over OkObjectResult

Comment: I doubt that it's as much a UTF-16 issue as that if Json.NET serializes the WebhookResponse, it won't create the JSON that Dialogflow expects. You're using the Protobuf JSON formatting by calling `ToString()`. That *is* what Dialogflow expects.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct. The reason why the text gets corrupted is mentioned at https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/50599456/dialogflow+fails+to+parse+the+json+response+from+my+webhook+seems+to+change+character+encoding

Comment: I'd suggest you edit out the final paragraph then :)